# Load a tiff file using JQuery and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tiff

I have a requirement to load a TIFF file using JQuery and Javascript.

I use the following code to load a 3-channel PNG file.

```
(function(file){ 
  var reader = new FileReader();
  $(reader).load(function(e){
    var img = new Image();
    $(img).load(function(){                
       $('#im-' + idx.toString()).attr('src', this.src);
    }
  })reader.readAsDataURL(file);
})(this.files[0]);
```

This code is not able to load the TIFF file which has 21 channels. Could anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: Does the browser you are testing this in support TIFF files as `<img>` sources in the first place?

Comment: Why are you making `reader` a jQuery object? It's not a DOM element. You don't need jQuery at all to read an image file, there's 0 DOM element involved.

Comment: Which antiquated version of jquery are you using?  Looks like you're using the [load event](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) which was removed some years ago.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fileTypes = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'tiff', 'tif', 'pdf']; //acceptable file types
  $("input:file").change(function(evt) {
    var parentEl = $(this).parent();
    $(this).parent().find("img.preview").remove();
    $(this).parent().find("canvas.preview").remove();
    var tgt = evt.target || window.event.srcElement,
      files = tgt.files;
    // FileReader support
    if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
      var fr = new FileReader();
      var extension = files[0].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
      var tif = false;
      var pdf = false;
      if (extension == "tiff" || extension == "tif")
        tif = true;
      fr.onload = function(e) {
        success = fileTypes.indexOf(extension) > -1;
        if (success) {
          if (tif) {
            //Using tiff.min.js library - https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js/tree/master
            console.debug("Parsing TIFF image...");
            //initialize with 100MB for large files
            Tiff.initialize({
              TOTAL_MEMORY: 100000000
            });
            var tiff = new Tiff({
              buffer: e.target.result
            });
            var tiffCanvas = tiff.toCanvas();
            $(tiffCanvas).css({
              "max-width": "100px",
              "width": "100%",
              "height": "auto",
              "display": "block",
              "padding-top": "10px"
            }).addClass("preview");
            $(parentEl).append(tiffCanvas);
          }  else {
            console.debug("render immmm");
            $(parentEl).append('<img src="' + fr.result + '" class="preview"/>');
          }
        }

      }

      fr.onloadend = function(e) {
        console.debug("Load End");
      }
      if (tif)
        fr.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
      else
        fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    }
    // Not supported
    else {
      // fallback -- perhaps submit the input to an iframe and temporarily store
      // them on the server until the user's session ends.
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rfvallina/Misc/master/pdf.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/seikichi/tiff.js/master/tiff.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Image Preview</h2>
    <label>Select a file (jpg, png, tiff)</label>
    <br />
    <div>
      <input type="file" />
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This doesn't support 32-bit TIFF files. I am supposed to load a 32-bit TIFF file containing 11 channels.

Comment: I am looking at another library - GEOTIFF https://towardsdatascience.com/geotiff-coordinate-querying-with-javascript-5e6caaaf88cf